# Is it possible to use laravel nova tool for not authenticated users?

Tags: laravel-nova

I'm trying to create custom reset password view that can include my custom field. I'm able to use this custom field for the tools that authenticated user use. The problems are, 1. How to redefine the parent layout. 2. How to prevent Nova guarding my custom routes to be able to use them by not authenticated user.

I've been researching for days trying to solve this. not sure if it solvable at all.